# How to label with numbers atoms when MoleculePlot3D

Tags: plotting, labeling, chemistry

I want to place a number on each atom (on a sphere) upon 3D plotting a molecule. For example, from:

`mol = Molecule["h2co"]; MoleculePlot3D[m, {1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}]`

I get this:

[image]

But, this is not what I want. Instead of having this legend, I would like to have labels on the atoms themselves, like this:

[image].

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 mol = Molecule["Formaldehyde"];
```

You can use the option [`AtomLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomLabels.html) (Introduced in version 13.0):

```
MoleculePlot3D[mol, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 AtomLabels -> Thread[Placed[ {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Center]],
 PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can construct a `Graphics3D` object using `mol["AtomCoordinates"]["Magnitudes"]` as `Text` positions and combine it with `MoleculePlot[...]` using `Show`:

```
 Show[MoleculePlot3D[mol], 
  Graphics3D[MapThread[Text, 
    {Style[#, 16] & /@ Range[4], mol["AtomCoordinates"]["Magnitudes"]}]]]
```

[image]