# Label the atoms of a molecule imported from an XYZ file

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling, chemistry

I would like to label the atoms of a molecule imported from an XYZ file. The only example that I found is the following ([How to label with numbers atoms when MoleculePlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242229/how-to-label-with-numbers-atoms-when-moleculeplot3d)):

```
 mol = Molecule["Formaldehyde"];

 Show[ MoleculePlot3D[mol], 
  Graphics3D[MapThread[Text, 
    {Style[#, 16] & /@ Range[4], mol["AtomCoordinates"]["Magnitudes"]}]]]
```

Could you please help me how to modify this code to take the molecule from an XYZ file, say from `"ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"`? And is there any way to label the atoms individually?

Comment: The most direct way would be to replace `Molecule["Formaldehyde"]` with `Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]`, and `Range[4]` with `Range[AtomCount[mol]]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you very much! It helped a lot! And is there any way to set individual labels for the atoms?

Comment: what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @JasonB. The version I am using is 12.3.

Comment: Replacing "Style[#, 16] & /@ Range[4]"  by "Style[#, 16] & /@ {"C", "O", "H", "H"} " should do what you want.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't have this functionality as bullet proof as it should be by the time version 12.3 was released, so this option is undocumented.  But it does work pretty well, and follows most of the conventions of [`VertexLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabels.html).

To label all atoms by their index use

```
mol = Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"];
MoleculePlot3D[mol, AtomLabels -> "AtomIndex"]
```

[image]

To label two specific atoms

```
MoleculePlot3D[mol, 
 AtomLabels -> {1 -> Placed[Style["bob", 22], Center], 2 -> "alice"}]
```

[image]

AtomLabels will be documented starting in the next version. It's been extended so you can use atom patterns on the left hand side of the rules, and molecule properties on the right hand side, like

```
MoleculePlot3D[mol, 
 AtomLabels -> {Atom[Except["H"]] -> 
    MoleculeProperty["AtomicNumber"]}, AtomLabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! The last question (I promise:)) is how to use superscripts and subscripts in `AtomLabels -> {1 -> Placed[Style["bob", 22], Center], 2 -> "alice"}]`?

Comment: You can put any expression as the first argument to `Placed`, for example `Style[Subscript["C", 1], 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]`

Comment: You may find this useful: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterSubscriptsAndSuperscripts.html

Comment: It is perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Now a very last question. If I would like to use C'_1, then how to achieve that the prime is above the superscript "1"?

Comment: `Subsuperscript["C", 1, "\[Prime]"]`